# Millions have spoken

Tags: word, wordplay

The question might have been: How many?

Millions have spoken!

> Thirteen
>
> With
>
> One
>
> Are
>
> Included

What 8 letter word are we talking about?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to the question is:

> **[MANDARIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandarin_Chinese)** - a language which not only *millions have spoken*, but **billions**, in fact!

How do we derive this? By spelling it out like so:

> Thirteen = **M** (the 13th letter of the alphabet)
>
>  With = **AND**
>
>  One = **A** (the indefinite article for something singular)
>
>  Are = **R** (phonetically)
>
>  Included = **IN**

Comment: And there it is! Thanks for not giving up.

Comment: @DrD A sudden flash of inspiration on seeing it again :) Often the way...

Comment: Also  you can use same logic for A as you used for M

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is that the answer is:

> Thirteen

I arrived here because:

> Thirteen is eight characters long and its the first (one) word in the blockquote.

However, I rethought the puzzle and arrived at:

> Fourteen

I based this answer on the fact that:

> There is some representation of the numbers one, two, and three (given as thirteen) available in the block quote in some form or another. The fact that two is a part of an acrostic can't be a coincidence. Also, "fourteen" is eight characters long and as such is a plausible answer. Given the fact that "one" is specified, it *may* be an instruction to look back to the first word of the block quote, which is subsequently related to the number three.

The only downside is:

> I was unable to tie the word "are" to either answer.